# Could SIGKILL fail?

Tags: linux, centos, kill-process

I've encountered this piece of behavior where even after issuing `SIGKILL` using `kill -9` the process is not terminating. the command in question here is `cat`

```
# ps -ef | grep 19275
root     19275     1  0 08:50 ?        00:00:00 [cat]
root     22964 21578  0 09:05 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 19275
# kill -9 19275
# echo $?
0
# ps -ef | grep 19275
root     19275     1  0 08:50 ?        00:00:00 [cat]
#
```

*some background*
I've executed this command `for ((i=0; i<28; i++)); do cat </dev/zero >${i} & done` as part of my test, for some strange reason when I tried to terminate this using

`pkill -TERM cat` did not work
`pkill -9 cat` did not work
`kill -9 pid` did not work

if memory is restriction here I do believe there is enough memory available here

```
# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             23          18           2           0           2           3
Swap:            59           2          56
```

any hints  ? apart from `reboot`

Comment: It might be in uninterruptible sleep, show output of `ps aux | grep '[1]9275'`

Comment: Are you root? Because that `cat` process is owned by `root` and nobody other than him will be allowed to kill that process, except the power-switch.

Comment: to see the state: `ps -o s 19275`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your logic it worked for me with k**ill -9**  and even with
**killall cat**, but it take some time to kill all 28 instances